# Error appeared when I changed default page in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2

First, I did not like the index.cshtml page is that it contains the signature of Web API ASP.net, the API link, ...so on. And it also it contains the footer as '2015 @ My Asp.net Application'.
So, is there a way that I can get rid of the header and signature? I found the solution as that could be at the master page, but I couldn't find the master page with extension (.master) in my application.
Please help me in getting rid of the header and signature of Asp.net Web API.

Second,  I set another page as 'Set page as Start page' or as default page. Then when I changed my mind and came back and made the index.cshtml page as default page as it was, I got Server Error (page not found).

Please help me in either one way where I can create a new html page to add my code in it, and I can make it as start page without problems.
Or at least, let me fix the error that occurred in the index.cshtml page, where I can come back to it and use it again.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC razor the master page is referred to as the _Layout.cshtml page it can be found inside Views->Shared.

To set the default page you would have to set the default action and controller in the routing table

Answer (score 0):

**Footer**

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd> Search Entire Solution for: "My Asp.net Application". This displays ***_Layout.cshtml*** as a search result.

**Default Page**

Go To *Project > Properties > Web*.
Remove *Start Action Specific Page* (make it blank).